# django getattr for ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, models

how to use getattr to get ManyToManyField value?

in model's save method :

```
getattr(Project.objects.filter(name=self.name)[0], 'type')
getattr(self, 'type')
getattr(Project.objects.filter(name=self.name)[0], 'user')
getattr(self, 'user')
```

I got this:

10kmop

10kmop

auth.User.None

auth.User.None

user is a ManyToManyField,  I got None here.

how can I got those user value?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. The "None" response absolutely does not mean that there is no User associated.

```
getattr(self, 'user')
```

just give you a link to associated User, but the represetion of this link is None.
You just have to get all the objects :
`getattr(self, 'user').all()`
should do the job.

I share here my working example. I use getattr in my custom tag :

```
@register.filter
def keyvalue(cur_model, key):
    if key == "item_components" :
        return getattr(cur_model, key).all()

    return getattr(cur_model, key)
```

item_components is ManyToMany field in my model.

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
Project.objects.filter(name=self.name).first().user
```

Comment: Well that just means you have no User associated with the Project.